# Xamarin Toast Message error (C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, toast, android-toast

I want to display a toast Message. If I'd do this in onCreate() it'd work fine. But I want to do it like this and I get an error:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference

What should I do?

```
public  void textToast(string textToDisplay) {               
    Toast.MakeText(this,
    textToDisplay, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
class SampleTabFragment : Fragment
{
    Button add;
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Tab, container, false);     
        add = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.add);      
        add.Click += Click;
        return view;
    }
    void Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {      
        main.textToast( "I like Toast!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What I would look at is if 'this' or the view within 'this' that the toast message is trying to display on top of is null in the context from which you are trying to show the toast message.

Comment: I would recommend just using the Activity that the Fragment is created in. You can use `getActivity()` in your `onAttach()` method to ensure it's a correct reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Java.Lang.NullPointerException` is triggered because you are manually creating and using an instance of `MainActivity`.

Instead of using a custom instance of `MainActivity` to display your toast message in `Click`, simplify your code to use the fragments existing activity reference:

```
public  void textToast(string textToDisplay) {               
    Toast.MakeText(this,
    textToDisplay, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}

class SampleTabFragment : Fragment
{
    Button add;

    // Remove manual creation code
    // MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    // ...

    void Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {      
        (Activity as MainActivity).textToast( "I like Toast!"); 
    }
}
```

This code assumes that the owning activity is always an instance of `MainActivity`.

See:

- [Fragment getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())
- [How to use the method of an Activity in a DialogFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266247/how-to-use-the-method-of-an-activity-in-a-dialogfragment/32324810#32324810)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, I think a good solution may be this one:

```
        public void makeToast(Context ctx, string str)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(ctx, str, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

And when you use it in every fragment you have, you can call it just writing:

```
makeToast(this.Activity, "test!");
```

Works for me, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but I'm going to use the solution of matthewrdev instead because I'll need to type less code if I'm going to make more toast messages.

Comment: @AlGrande I just wanted to offer a different solution, thanks for the comment :)