# Problems with reading text file from assets (xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, text, xamarin

I have problem with reading simple txt from assets directory. I can't really figure out why it doesn't work and what is wrong.

Here is the code of method I wrote:

```
        private string ReadFile(){
        var stream = Assets.Open ("sampleText.txt");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (stream);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd ();
        sr.Close ();
        return text;
    }
```

And here is the error:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2970/46c3f7e0/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2970/46c3f7e0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:596 
at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.get_Assets () [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2970/46c3f7e0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.cs:154
```

I had no problems with running my whole application on windows, just I have problems to run it on android. Tried various things, like instance of AssetManager, but didn't work as well.

The text file is marked as AndroidAsset.

This is my `TextChangeBench`:

```
public class TextChangeBench : Activity
{
    public TextChangeBench (){}

    private void SaveFile(string[] tab){

        string saveLocation = "sampleTextReworked.txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (saveLocation);
        foreach (string s in tab) {
            sw.Write (s);
        }
        sw.Close ();
    }

    private string ReadFile(){
        var stream = Assets.Open ("sampleText.txt");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (stream);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd ();
        sr.Close ();
        return text;
    }
    public void ChangeText(){
        try{
            File.Delete("sampleTextReworked.txt");
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){Console.WriteLine (e);}

        try{
            string text = ReadFile ();
            char c;
            string[] newTab = new string[text.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                c = (char)text [i];
                if (Char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString().ToLower();
                }
                else if (Char.IsLower(c))
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString().ToUpper();
                }
                else
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            SaveFile(newTab);
        }
        catch(Exception e){Console.WriteLine ("{0} ", e);}
    }
}
```

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
[Activity (Label = "csBench", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button startButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.start);
        startButton.Click += delegate {

            MathBench mb = new MathBench ();
            TextChangeBench tcb = new TextChangeBench ();
            PassedTime pt = new PassedTime ();
            EditText et = (EditText)FindViewById (Resource.Id.textInfo);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                pt.StartMeasuring ();
                //mb.Silnia (25);
                //mb.Fibonacci (32);
                //mb.BubbleSort ();
                tcb.ChangeText ();
                if (i == 4) {
                    pt.StopMeasuring ();

                    et.SetText(pt.ReturnResult(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                    //et.SetText(pt.ReturnResult().ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine(pt.ReturnResult ());
                    pt.ResetTimers ();
                }
            }  
        };

    }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the build action of `sampleText.txt` set to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: Yes, it is as I mentioned.

Comment: which specific line throws the error?

Comment: The one with Assets.Open

Comment: are you sure the context you're running in has a valid reference to AssetManager?

Comment: By itself, that code is fine. Could you include the surrounding code for `ReadFile()`? Generally a `Java.Lang.NullPointerException` means the activity has been disposed and is an invalid state.

Comment: @matthewrdev http://pastebin.com/WkKa7CUf here is the class

Comment: @Jason could you elaborate please? I don't have yet much experience in mobile developing, and this context was my nightmare today... :)

Comment: @definitelyNotLazy How are you using `TextChangeBench`? Where does the instance of it come from?

Comment: it's running within an Activity, which should have a valid reference to Assets.  That answers my question

Comment: @matthewrdev I call ChangeText method from main activity, code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/xEHS4UQu

Comment: @definitelyNotLazy Manually creating an instance of `TextChangeBench` (which inherits `Activity`) bypasses the frameworks setup logic. This puts the activity into an invalid state.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264801/xamarin-toast-message-error-c/36272810#36272810

Comment: @definitelyNotLazy Could you please update the question to include the code for `TextChangeBench` and `MainActivity` and I'll answer the question in depth.

Comment: @definitelyNotLazy Just dumped the code in for you so others have some context to the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error is occurring because manually creating an instance of an activity such as `TextChangeBench` circumvents the Android frameworks setup process leaving the activity in an invalid state.

Activities are used as a point of user interaction, binding a view/screen to logic in your application. As `TextChangeBench` only implements application logic, it doesn't need to be derived from `Activity` and would be better suited as a plain C# class.

Remove the inheritance to activity to simplify the code for `TextChangeBench`. This means we no longer have access to the `Assets` property thus cannot retrieve assets. We can fix this by instead using the global application context:

```
var stream = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("sampleText.txt");
```

The combination of removing the activity inheritance and using the global context to access the asset manager will fix the `Java.Lang.NullPointerException`.

The final code would look like this:

```
public class TextChangeBench 
{
    private void SaveFile(string[] tab)
    {

        string saveLocation = "sampleTextReworked.txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveLocation);
        foreach (string s in tab)
        {
            sw.Write(s);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }

    private string ReadFile()
    {
        var stream = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("sampleText.txt");

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        return text;
    }
    public void ChangeText()
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete("sampleTextReworked.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }

        try
        {
            string text = ReadFile();
            char c;
            string[] newTab = new string[text.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                c = (char)text[i];
                if (Char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString().ToLower();
                }
                else if (Char.IsLower(c))
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString().ToUpper();
                }
                else
                {
                    newTab[i] = text[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            SaveFile(newTab);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("{0} ", e); }
    }
}
```

See:

- [Xamarin Toast Message error (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264801/xamarin-toast-message-error-c/36272810#36272810)
- [How to use the method of an Activity in a DialogFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266247/how-to-use-the-method-of-an-activity-in-a-dialogfragment/32324810#32324810)